# Answer posted after another is Accepted is the better choice

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

So this question is sparked by admittedly an answer [I posted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75964/can-contingency-plus-dispel-magic-be-used-to-mitigate-all-negative-wild-magic-ou) after an answer was already accepted but [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53541/did-spirit-guardians-just-wipe-out-the-orc-army) is also spurred me to post it.

If an answer is accepted and a later answer is a better fit and/or more accurate is the only recourse to let the voting resolve it assuming the OP of the question ever checks back on their already assumedly answered question? Or in the case of the linked instance where nitsua60 posted a bounty in what appears to be an attempt to sway the changing of the answer, in this case the original was correct until Crawford recanted and clarified.

Is there a way to draw the eye to help encourage "re-voting" with this new information?

First ever question so please let me know if you need clarification to help with your answer(s).

Comment: I think this is in effect a duplicate of [When rules change but votes don't, how to handle it?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6071)

Comment: More or less, yes, the title threw me off since the rules had not necessarily changed for my instigating answer but did for the one that nitsua60 posted on. I will withdraw my question in light of this, thanks. Thought I had read all the ones tagged as "accepted-answer".

Comment: I've undeleted this and marked it as a duplicate because duplicates are *good*! We like them; they're useful. They help people find the information they're looking for, by having multiple different ways of asking about a problem pointing to the same solutions.